# Annotation Tool for Object Detection compatible with HDFS

Tags: software-development

We used CVAT (https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/cvat) in the past as an annotation tool for object detection. CVAT however can not be integrated into the Hadoop-based Architecture, hence it needs to be locally installed for each team member. Is there an existing annotation tool that is compatabile with the HDFS Architecture? Thanks much in advance.